# iOS video display

Tags: ios, iphone, video, cell

Hi I'm trying to make app with vid display, I have `didSelectRowAtIndex` for the cell once touched goes to the `detailedViewController` which would have the video auto playing once loaded and the comments of the vid and the uploader username, how do I display the video in the cell then once the cell touched then display the video in the `detailedViewController` and also I want the videos backend to be with parse so uploading the videos to the app which would get uploaded to parse as it would be the backend, how do I do this and if you could please point me in the right direction thank you

Comment: Do you want to play the video in each cell.. or just display the video..

Comment: Just display the video in the cell like youtube and the once touched goes to the detailedViewController and that's where the vid will auto play

Comment: then display the thumbnail of the video in the cell.. and load the video when the cell is touched..

Comment: Do you have link to something with an example to show how to do this

Comment: are you able to get the list of videos and their url's from youtube..

Comment: they are videos that i downloaded from the web .mp4

Comment: there is a default set of videos that i want to put in the app then there is also an upload feature

Comment: So, the videos are with you.. you want to display them in the app and also with features like play and upload them to youtube via parse.

Comment: NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: ofType:nil];

Comment: pathForResource: i need to put an array of videos here, see im trying this way so i can understand the process of this operation, then once i know how to do it i want to do it with parse load the video lists from parse on to the app in different viewControllers

Comment: and also upload from the iphone itself from the library to the app thats what i meant about upload

Comment: videos you have recorded to the app